# SQL Server database table to oracle server using WebAPI [scheduled]

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, scheduling

I have an application which is build recently and pushes data into SQL Server.
And I have another application which uses an Oracle database and gets data manually so far.

Now I need a way how I can insert the data that comes into SQL Server into Oracle daily.

Is there a way to do this with Web API in combination with schedulers?

Customer wants this to be done with Web API with some scheduling. I'm not sure how it can be done.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of SSIS/SQL Server are you on?

Comment: it's SQL Server 2014